# Getting started for executing retro emulator-newbie

Tags: motorola-680x0

I was going through the link https://github.com/kstenerud/Musashi/ and downloaded 68k emulator. Since I am a newbie, I could not just start executing the application. I could not find comprehensive documentation of getting started. Help required in this regard.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because how to start up a modern computer program is off-topic, even if the program is an emulation engine for an old CPU. The readme.md explains how to use the downloaded code and points to example programs using the emulator.

Comment: @Justme I disagree. Getting started on emulating old computers is part of retrocomputing and I really wish this pointless gatekeeping would stop. It's not like this site is overwhelmed with questions. Why are we discouraging people from retrocomputing?

Comment: @JeremyP Context matters. Do you think it is OK to ask here about how to compile and run a random project downloaded from Internet on a modern computer, just because the random project happens to be a M68K CPU emulator core, with only an example platform provided without emulating any existing retro platform? Asking how to compile the github project if there is compile or dependency errors should be asked from the maintainer of the project, as it has nothing to do with anything retro.

Comment: Should probably be asked on superuser

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Though the asker doesn’t seem to realize (and it’s hardly obvious at first glance), this is a programming problem, which means it would be out of scope on SuperUser.

Comment: @Justme No, of course it's not OK to ask about downloading and running a random project. Nobody has said it is. However, this is a 68xxx emulation project, **not** a random project. It is an emulation of a retro CPU. Getting it to work may be something beyond the skill of the asker, but that doesn't make it invalid as a question about retro computing.

Comment: @JeremyP My interpretation of the rules is that it is off-topic and on the list of questions to avoid. Specifically, this is a question regarding writing (or rather, using, or just compiling) code that emulates retrocomputing features (only the bare CPU with no actual existing machine but a barebones demo hardware). For example, how to compile/run/configure an emulator like DosBox would be just as much off-topic and should be asked from DosBox folks on DosBox help/support forums. See https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @justme I agree that the rules, as they stand, allow the closing of such questions, but this rule is **bullshit**. It's just an excuse for people to gatekeeper the topic. Is it not obvious to you that the first step of retro computing, if you don't have original hardware, is to get an emulator working. And I don't agree that getting DOSBox to run is off topic. DOS is a retro operating system. Again I point out that this site is not overrun with questions of any sorting it is just wrong to suggest it would be harmed by not turning away people who want to run emulators.

Comment: @JeremyP this might be something you’d like to bring up on meta instead.

Comment: I've reopened this for now to see which way it gets voted. It's a tough one - emulation in general isn't always the best fit unless it's about retro software, sounds like OP would like to start developing 68k code though, and that would be probably viewed as on topic.

Comment: @MattLacey Mind to look into history? It has already been closed on [Feb 25th](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/posts/29562/timeline#history_3fe8de8c-5bc6-4dfa-902d-d984661ce61e) by 5 regular votes. Not to mention that the only answer rightful points out that the issues lay outside the retro sphere. So why overruling the decision the community already made - even more, as of now it's impossible to vote again for closure,at least that's what it tells me when trying to vote . What kind of screwed up game is this?

Comment: @MattLacey I don’t think it is our duty to second-guess what the asker might want to do and judge whether the question is on-topic on that basis. It should only depend on what’s written in the question. Besides, even if it were on-topic… it’s still terribly vague to the point where it’s not clear how it should be answered.

Comment: Considering to vote to close as "need more clarification" since I find it unclear what type of help is needed.

Comment: Frankly, I don't care that much. The internet is a hostile enough place as it is without people putting the boot in because they deem something to be slightly off topic for a site. Either way, it's been closed again so will leave it as is. I only reopened beucase it there were still flags to deal with even after it had been closed.

Comment: @MattLacey One of the problems with RC.SE, if not the biggest is that it essentially encompasses everything computing - and no issue about computing is really new never been before, nor can be tweaked that way. Easy visible how other sites redirect less mainstream questions that naturally would be their turf to RC.SE because of some reason. Similar do we cover every hard and software there ever was.Last but not least, there will always be some disagreeing no matter if a compromise is settled. So yes, that burden can noone take off of your shoulders.

Answer (score 10):

Frame challenge: That piece of software is not the place to start, as a newbie.

What that Github project provides is source code for a 68000 family processor emulator. But it's just a processor emulator, it does not emulate a complete computer. You need development tools (such as GCC, XCode, or Microsoft Visual Studio) and some knowledge of using them to turn the source into a library, and then you need to write programs to use the library. What kind of programs? That depends on what you specifically want to do.

I suggest you make up your mind what you specifically want to do, and then ask a question about that. Possibilities include:

- Learning 68000-family assembler programming.
- Running programs written for a specific 68000-based computer.
- Modifying programs to run on some specific 68000-based computer.

Comment: I did follow the readme file and just ran the makefile. I did not know what to do next? Sorry if this forum does not entertain newbie

Comment: @gari Write your own software using that library. The example subdirectory contains a demo program you can study.

Comment: @gari: See revised the answer.

Comment: I tried compiling the program from the example folder but ran into several errors which includes missing dependencies and syntax errors. Can anyone explain me the right way to generate the executable? or any can anybody suggest an alternative?

Comment: @gari it depends on what you want to do. If you want a 68000 system, you'd do better to find an emulator already built for your platform (e.g. Windows/Linux/macOS). If you are not experienced with C programming, this project is a bad place to start.

Comment: @gari `make -C example`, with GCC installed, worked for me; without knowing what you tried, on which OS and compiler toolchain, we cannot be sure what went wrong. But this is more of a Stack Overflow question anyway.

Comment: I tried using codeblocks. I also tried using mingw but i do get lots of errors. can you please further guide